# Showing sitemap in google search result

Tags: xml-sitemap

I want to show a sitemap in google's search result. Like - when you search for "cnet" in google, it shows the result of www.cnet.com with a sitemap of some links. something like this-

```
Product reviews and prices, software downloads, and tech news - CNET
CNET is the premier destination for tech product reviews, news, price comparisons, free software downloads, daily videos, and podcasts.
www.cnet.com/ - Cached - SimilarCNET Download
Reviews
Cell Phones
TVs Laptops
Digital Cameras
Tablets
Printers
More results from cnet.com »
```

I want to do this for my site too. my site is celebratinglifebd.com. I have added/varified the site to google webmaster central. I have generated a xml sitemap and successfully added to google webmaster central(http://www.celebratinglifebd.com/sitemap.xml). it shows empty for "URLs in web index". everything seems okay, but it is not showing the sitemap in search result. I am searching with "celebrating life" and it comes up in 1st page at number 8. i have generated the sitemap from - http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not do this yourself
Google automatically generate this while browsing your site.
You can submit a sitemap to Google for helping them build it, but no guarantee that they will build it !

Comment: it takes time too ! [from 3days to 2 week, so have patience]

Comment: How can I add keywords for google? I have added meta tags in my website. But keywords in webmaster tools are different. how can I use perfect keyword?

Comment: keyword in webmaster shows which keyword is effective in Google's view and how can they help you to get hits ! If your site is less than a month old then you have to wait, until Google gets all the data needed for a better searching ! I'll also recommended you to publish your site's link in some good sites [for free or some money] coz it will worth it ! Have a good luck :)

Comment: I also experienced a search results sitemap appearing and disappearing again. No clue why, nothing about the site changed (third-party–hosted Wordpress blog with XML sitemap, SEO, Google webmaster tools and all).

Answer (score 8):

I think this article explains it very well: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334