# Show sitemap for my website in google search result

Tags: php, xml, seo

I want to show a sitemap in google's search result. Like - when you search for "cnet" in google, it shows the result of www.cnet.com with a sitemap of some links. something like this-

Product reviews and prices, software downloads, and tech news - CNET
CNET is the premier destination for tech product reviews, news, price comparisons, free software downloads, daily videos, and podcasts.
www.cnet.com/ - Cached - SimilarCNET Download
Reviews
Cell Phones
TVs Laptops
Digital Cameras
Tablets
Printers
More results from cnet.com »

I want to do this for my site too. my site is celebratinglifebd.com. I have added/varified the site to google webmaster central. I have generated a xml sitemap and successfully added to google webmaster central(http://www.celebratinglifebd.com/sitemap.xml). it shows empty for "URLs in web index". everything seems okay, but it is not showing the sitemap in search result. I am searching with "celebrating life" and it comes up in 1st page at number 8. i have generated the sitemap from - http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/.

Comment: Google shows sitemap for established sites not new sites or sites having less views.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing sitemap in google search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685340/showing-sitemap-in-google-search-result)

Answer (score 1):

Google display several links for long established authoritative websites, this has nothing to do with the sitemaps you have submitted to the google webmaster central. The sitemap only helps google to crawle your website better (but it also does not guarantee that all links in your sitemap will be included in the index).

Just keep working on your website, build more links to it, add great content and maybe one day it will become an authority and show up with a "sitemap" in the search results :)